# Streaming SAX XML Processing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, cocoa, streaming, sax

NSXMLParser allows SAX parsing of either an NSData block or from a URL source.

The problem is that both these methods require the entire XML source to be known before parsing begins.

Suppose I have a stream of XML Data (say a sequence of NSData objects) and I want to process the stream using NSXMLParser or another cocoa class, how can I do this without needing to have the whole document to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at Apple's [XMLPerformance](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project, which uses libxml2 to perform streamed parsing.